# I want to ask a related question about the MFC ClistView class

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I want to design a project relationship manage system. I used the single document class recommended by mfc wizard to build.  `CSingleDocTemplate` by

```
RUNTIME_CLASS(CPrmDoc);
RUNTIME_CLASS(CMainFrame);
RUNTIME_CLASS(CPrmView));
```

Created.And i create a listnode to save project infomation.I use DataNode Class to store the read data, and use DataProc class to manage linked list. In the Class `CPrmView`, I use afx_msg function `afx_msg void OnFileRead()` to transfer The object `m_pDataProc` of the `CDataProc` class is used to save and store the read item information.But，int the void `CFileView::OnUpdate(CView\* pSender, LPARAM lHint, CObject\* pHint)` why i can not continue use object `m_pDataProc`.

```
void CFileView::OnFileRead() 
{
    // TODO: Add your command handler code here
    AfxMessageBox("33");
    m_pDataProc = new CDataProc;
    m_pDataProc->RemoveAllNode();
    CFileDialog ChooseFile(TRUE, _T("txt"), "prms", OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT,  _T("Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|"));
    if(ChooseFile.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        
        CString strFilePath = ChooseFile.GetPathName(); 
        m_pDataProc->ReadPrmsFile(strFilePath);
        CString test;
        test.Format("%d", m_pDataProc->m_nValidCount);
        AfxMessageBox(test);
    }
    else 
    {
        AfxMessageBox("   ");
    }
}
```

Why i can not to continue use object `pDataProc`.

```
void CFileView::OnUpdate(CView* pSender, LPARAM lHint, CObject* pHint) 
{

    if (lHint == 0x5A) 
    {   
        // m_pDataProc =        
        GetListCtrl().DeleteAllItems(); 
    
        CString strChangeState = (LPCTSTR) pHint;
        int nIndex = FindTypeIndex(strIndexArray, strChangeState, 10);
/*      strChangeState.Format("%d", nIndex);*/  

        int nC = m_pDataProc ->m_nValidCount;
        CString ntest;
        ntest.Format("%d", nIndex);
        AfxMessageBox(ntest);           
                CDataNode* pDataNode = m_pDataProc->GetDataHead();

    }
    CListView::OnUpdate (pSender, lHint, pHint);
}
```

Can you tell me how to continue to use in other functions, the address pointed to by `m_pDataProc` in void `CFileView::OnFileRead()`? Thank you very much.

Comment: Better use the 'CDocument::Serialize()' function instead of `FileRead()`;

Comment: _"Why i can not to continue use object pDataProc"_: what is `pDataProc`?

Comment: Today I found out that you can use this function CPrmsDoc* CFileView::GetDocument() created by MFC class wizard
{ return (CPrmsDoc*)m_pDocument; } to obtain the data read by CStudioFile::ReadString in the CDataProc class. Thank you for answering questions